# Show custom html on mouse hover angular 2

Tags: angular

Is there any package or way to display small html design when the user hover on specific word? just like the facebook when you hover on username you can see his cover and avatar in small design.

Comment: you can write up a little directive thats provides this function

Answer (score 0):

use `<mat-menu>` of angular material.

link: https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview.

Answer (score 0):

You can use popover for add custom template
example link : [example link](http://jsfiddle.net/U4GLT/3188/)

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="customDirectives">
    <div> <span custom-popover popover-html="Some Popover Text" popover-placement="bottom" popover-label="Label"></span>

    </div>
</div>
```

**DIRECTIVE**

```
customDirectives = angular.module('customDirectives', []);
customDirectives.directive('customPopover', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<span>{{label}}</span>',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            scope.label = attrs.popoverLabel;
            $(el).popover({
                trigger: 'hover',
                html: true,
                content: attrs.popoverHtml,
                placement: attrs.popoverPlacement
            });
        }
    };
});

angular.module('CustomComponents', ['customDirectives']);
```